# Having two different names in two countries - complications for birth certificate?

Tags: names, birth-certificate, italy-aire

I'm an italian citizen living in Sweden (waiting for swedish citizenship). I want to remove my italian surname and get my husband's surname. This is easily done in Sweden but the new name won't be recognised in Italy.

While I don't think I will have any problem travelling between the countries, I wonder if I will have issues when registering the birth of my son in the italian records and then requesting italian citizenship for my kid.
For example if I want to register the birth in Italy, the mother's name on the birth certificate won't match with my original Italian name. Which might mean I can't request italian citizenship for my son? Am I wrong?

Other issues like heredity in case of death in the family I guess can be solved by always having italian documents updated and valid but I'm wondering what other complications there will be, eventually how to deal with the practicality of having two different identities?

Answer (score 1):

> Which might mean I can't request italian citizenship for my son?

It shouldn't mean that.  You're still you, after all.  You should have a paper trail connecting your identity with your Italian name to your Swedish name.  That is, you should have a document showing the change in your name in Swedish law.  This could be a marriage certificate, a naturalization certificate, or a document that has no other purpose than to show the change in your name.

Even if Italian law does not recognize your name change, it should recognize that your name is different in Swedish law and that the Swedish birth certificate showing your Swedish name is proof that you are the mother of your child.

> how to deal with the practicality of having two different identities?

You won't have two different identities; you'll have one identity with multiple names.  This isn't all that uncommon.  All you need is to be able to link both names to your single identity.

Comment: To be useful to prove the name change, the Swedish name change document should have both the old and new names, as well as enough details about the original poster to make it clear it is the same person who is dealing with the Italian authorities. It might be wise to obtain a certified translation into Italian at the time the document is created.